# Expected Tosses To Get THH sequence

Tags: probability, statistics

What is the expected number of tosses of a fair coin to see a $THH$ sequence? Here is my approach:

Here are the different cases:

1. We get $THH$ straight away in $3$ throws (probability $\frac{1}{8}$).
2. We first get $H$ (probability $\frac{1}{2}$), in which case we restart and number of tosses is $\mathbb{E}(X+1)$
3. We get $TT$ (probability $\frac{1}{4}$). In this case we need $\mathbb{E}(X ~|~ T)$ as first toss is a $T$.
4. We get $THT$ (probability $\frac{1}{8}$). Once again, in this case we need $\mathbb{E}(X~|~T)$ as first toss is a $T$.

Thus, putting this together:
$$\mathbb{E}(X) = 3\cdot\frac{1}{8} + \mathbb{E}(X+1)\cdot\frac{1}{2} + \mathbb{E}(X~|~T)(\frac{1}{4}+ \frac{1}{8})$$

Now, let's find $\mathbb{E}(X~|~T) = \mathbb{E}(THH~|~T) = \mathbb{E}(Y)$:

1. We flip two $H$ immediately after the first $T$ (probability $\frac{1}{4}$)
2. We flip a $T$ after the first $T$ (probability $\frac{1}{2}$), so we restart and the new expectation is $\mathbb{E}(Y)+1$
3. We flip a $H$ and then $T$ after the first $T$ to get $THT$ (probability $\frac{1}{4}$), and so we restart with expectation $\mathbb{E}(Y)+2$

Solving for $\mathbb{E}(Y)$:
$$\mathbb{E}(Y) = 2\cdot\frac{1}{4} + (\mathbb{E}(Y)+1)\cdot\frac{1}{2} + (\mathbb{E}(Y)+2)\cdot\frac{1}{4} 
     = 6$$

Plugging this back into the original equation for $\mathbb{E}(X)$ and solving we get $\mathbb{E}(X)= 6.25$ when the answer is $8$. Can someone please explain where I went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are not correctly counting the toss of obtaining $T$ in your last terms of the first equation. Your computation of $\texttt E[Y]$ is correct. However,

$$\texttt E[X] = 3\times \frac18 + \left(1 + \texttt E[X]\right)\frac12 + \left(2 + \texttt E[Y]\right)\frac14 + \left(3 + \texttt E[Y]\right)\frac18$$

Comment: Thank you! You're right, I forgot to include the added tosses for the last 2 cases.

Answer (score 1):

You could have computed it more efficiently had you recognised that there are only two cases:

1. First toss is $H$, and the game is restarted and number of tosses is $E(X+1)$
2. First toss is $T$, then the game ends once consecutive $H$s appear and number of tosses is $E(Y+1)$

$$
E(X)=\frac{1}{2}E(X+1) + \frac{1}{2}E(Y+1)
$$

Your calculation of $E(Y)=6$ is correct, solving the equation yields $E(X)=8$